# Update calculation result if certain input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

I'm coding a simple page to calculate values based on selecting options.
I've faced a problem in calculation process, which is the result isn't instantly appear, But i should add a value to input like (0 or something else then delete it) to complete the calculate process, which isn't required it's optional if user have a balance.
Maybe my details isn't enough but there is an example.

I would like to know what is wrong in my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   var vat = 15;
   var price = 0;
   var price_vat = 0;
   $("#products").change(function(){
    pk_vat = vat;
    $("#products option:selected").each(function (){
     pk_vat *= parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
     price = parseInt($(this).data("price"));
     price_vat = parseInt($(this).data("price"));

     $("#cur_bal_b").on('input change keyup past', function(evt){
      var value = evt.target.value
      var current = parseFloat($(this).val());
      var remaining = price - current;
      var remaining_vat = ((price - current) * 14 / 100 );
      if (value.length === 0) {
       $("#rem_b").val(price);
       $("#vat_rem_b").val(pk_vat.toFixed(2));
       $("#tot_b").val((price + pk_vat).toFixed(2));
      } else {
       $("#rem_b").val(remaining);
       $("#vat_rem_b").val(remaining_vat.toFixed(2));
       $("#tot_b").val((remaining + remaining_vat).toFixed(2));
      }
      
     });

    });  
    pk_vat = pk_vat / 100;
    price_vat = price_vat + pk_vat;  

    $("#price_b").val(price);
    $("#price_vat_b").val(price_vat.toFixed(2));
   });
  });
```

```css
table, td {border:1px solid #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Products Name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Price &amp; VAT</td>
    <td>Current Balance</td>
    <td>Remaining</td>
    <td>VAT Remaining</td>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
<select id="products">
<option id="b_0" value="" data-price="0">Please Select</option>
<option id="b_1" value="s_140" data-price="10.00">product a</option>
<option id="b_2" value="s_250" data-price="20.00">product b</option>
<option id="b_3" value="s_600" data-price="30.00">product c</option>
<option id="b_4" value="m_140" data-price="40.00">product d</option>
<option id="b_5" value="m_250" data-price="50.00">product e</option>
<option id="b_6" value="u_140" data-price="60.00">product f</option>
<option id="b_7" value="u_250" data-price="70.00">product g</option>
<option id="b_8" value="u_600" data-price="80.00">product h</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input name="Price_B" type="text" id="price_b" value="0" disabled="disabled" /></td>
<td><input name="Price_Vat_B" type="text" id="price_vat_b" value="0" disabled="disabled" /></td>
<td><input class="cur_bal" name="Current_Balance" type="text" id="cur_bal_b" placeholder="Current Balance&hellip;" autocomplete="off" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" /></td>
<td><input name="Remaining" type="text" id="rem_b" value="0" disabled="disabled" /></td>
<td><input name="Vat_Remaining" type="text" id="vat_rem_b" value="0" disabled="disabled" /></td>
<td style="width:100px;"><input name="Total_b" type="text" id="tot_b" value="0" disabled="disabled" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have your calculations happening in the input field's event handler. That doesn't fire until someone does something with the input.

Instead of defining the calculation  in the event handler, create a separate function that calculates the results. Then you can call this function from the select's change handler as well as the input's handler. When the select changes, or the input is accessed, the number would update through this function.

(On another note, it looks like you define the input handler inside the select's handler. This means that every time the select is changed, yet another handler is being added to that input. I'd recommend putting the input handler next to the select handler, not inside it.)